# Can we prove that set of all nested continued fractions $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ and the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ are homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, number-theory, real-numbers, fractions

Let us have a general sequence $(a_n)\in\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ ($a: n\in\mathbb{N}\mapsto a_n\in\mathbb{N}$).

{Question 1}

If we simply insert that sequence into the nested fractions, then we get
$$a_0+\frac{1}{a_1+\frac{1}{a_2+\frac{1}{a_3+\dots}}}\in\mathbb{R}^+$$

It seems that for any such sequence we get a converging sequence, which is a real number. So correct me if I am wrong, but that seems a straightforward bijection of all such sequences onto positive real numbers. Also, we are able to build a ordering simply in the following manner:

```
def compare(a,b):
    i = 0
    while (a[i]==b[i]):
        if i%2 == 0:
            if a[i]<b[i]:
                return "a > b"
            elif a[i]> b[i]:
                return "a < b"
            else:
                i += 1
        else:
            if a[i]<b[i]:
                return "a < b"
            elif a[i]> b[i]:
                return "a > b"
            else:
                i += 1
```

I never saw that construction alongside others like Dedekind, Weierstrass or Cantor approaches.

{Question 2}

Have anybody investigated the topologies on $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ for this mapping to be continous?

UPD:

I found a 1982 publication https://leopard.tu-braunschweig.de/servlets/MCRFileNodeServlet/dbbs_derivate_00031201/Rieger_A_new_approach_to_the_real_numbers.pdf

Rieger, Georg Johann A new approach to the real numbers
(motivated by continued fractions) Veröffentlicht in:
Abhandlungen der Braunschweigischen
Wissenschaftlichen Gesellschaft Band 33, 1982,
S.205-217

UPD2:

The main problem of the definition above is $0$, since $1=0+\frac{1}{1}$. So one way or another we need to factorize $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$.

UPD3:

It seems that the correspondance is more complicated, like
$$(\mathbb{Z}×\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N})\cup (\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcup_{(a_k)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}^n}\{( a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots, a_n,0,0,0,\dots)\}\sim\mathbb{R}$$

Comment: There are two continued fraction representations for each rational. You'll have to choose one if you want a bijection. Representations are just a naming scheme for the reals, they don't impact and of their properties. It's the same distinction as between numbers and numerals.

Comment: AFAIK, two representations appear, when we are using negative integers, but we are mapping only positive integers into positive reals. And after that we can model all reals as a pair of positive reals like in a model of integers through perspective of natural numbers.

Comment: But nothing changes topologically. It's a representation, not a property of the real numbers.

Comment: Maybe I was not that clear on my question. First question is about that we have the axiomatics of real numbers, but we have three models: Dedekind's model, Cantor's model and Weierstrass's model. Purely from th logical point of view. But do we have some nested continued fractions model? Or there are some problems with it?

Comment: On the second question, I am asking more about articles for further reading. Specifically on the topologies on $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Since real-valued numbers are uncountable infinite, maybe you could start to prove that $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ is not countable infinite, otherwise it cannot be true I think.

Comment: $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ is obvioulsy uncountable, since $2^\mathbb{N}$ (and exactly equal to $\mathfrak{C}$ by cardinality) is uncountable. I found some literature  Rieger, “A new approach to the real numbers (motivated by continued fractions),” Abhandlungen der Braunschweigischen Wissenschaftlichen Gesellschaft, vol. 33, pp. 205–217, 1982.

Comment: If $0$ isn't a natural number then you only get irrational numbers this way, and if $0$ is a natural number then you need to say something about uniqueness. Maybe something like this can be made to work but I don't really see the point. It's very difficult to define operations on continued fractions (already addition is difficult, let alone multiplication) but very easy for Cauchy sequences or Dedekind cuts.

Comment: Well, it is not really that hard. As I see, For real $\alpha,\beta$ we have $\min\{p_n,p_{n+1}\}<\alpha<\max\{p_n,p_{n+1}\}$ and $\min\{q_n,q_{n+1}\}<\beta<\max\{q_n,q_{n+1}\}$, thus we are able to simply conclude that $\min\{p_n,p_{n+1}\}+\min\{q_n,q_{n+1}\}<\alpha+\beta<\max\{p_n,p_{n+1}\}+\max\{q_n,q_{n+1}\}$ and $\min\{p_n,p_{n+1}\}\times \min\{q_n,q_{n+1}\}<\alpha \times \beta<\max\{p_n,p_{n+1}\}\times \max\{q_n,q_{n+1}\}$. Just with ordering. We have that $p_n\to \alpha, q_n\to\beta$, The point is "Why not?"

Comment: Moreover, It seems to be done in Rieger, Georg Johann A new approach to the real numbers (motivated by continued fractions) Veröffentlicht in: Abhandlungen der Braunschweigischen Wissenschaftlichen Gesellschaft Band 33, 1982, S.205-217

Comment: So, it is indeed some altering of Cauchy sequences in more algoritmised way. Could you give me an example when zero breraks the uniqueness. I do not see the example.

Comment: OK, I see when it comes  nonbijective, you mean like if we have $\frac{2}{3}=0+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2}}$ in one case and then we have $0+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1}}}$. Something like that,  so we will have the same rational number for finite (0,1,1,1) and (0,1,2)

Comment: the main problem in this definintion is that $0+\frac{1}{1}=1$, thus $1=0+\frac{1}{0+\frac{1}{1}}=0+\frac{1}{0+\frac{1}{0+\frac{1}{1}}}=0+\frac{1}{0+\frac{1}{0+\frac{1}{0+\frac{1}{1}}}}=\dots$.